# WICKET: Updating a self-made Panel

Tags: refresh, wicket, panel

ive got the following Problem:
my self-made video-class (extending Panel) doesnt get updated, if its model changes.

Thats the current state:
I got a Class "A" with a ListChoice. This Class creates the Panel "descrPanel", which gets a Model, containing the current selected Item of the ListChoice. It is updated, when the User selects something in the ListChoice (The ListChoice got an AjaxBehaviour, updating the descrPanel via target.add(descrPanel)):

**Class A:**

```java
    PropertyModel<Exercise> currExerciseModel = new PropertyModel<Exercise>(this,"selectedExercise");
    final ExerciseDescriptionPanel descrPanel = new ExerciseDescriptionPanel("descrPanelTag", currExerciseModel);

    descrPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

In Class ExerciseDescriptionPanel, i inserted my self-made Video-Class (extending Panel). Also i inserted a MultiLineLabel:

**Class ExerciseDescriptionPanel**

```java
public class ExerciseDescriptionPanel extends Panel {

private IModel<Exercise> model;
private Exercise exercise;

public ExerciseDescriptionPanel(String id, IModel<Exercise> model) {
    super(id, model);
    this.model = model;

MultiLineLabel mll = new MultiLineLabel("mll", new Model() { 
        @Override 
        public String getObject() {  
            if (ExerciseDescriptionPanel.this.getModel().getObject() != null){
                return ExerciseDescriptionPanel.this.getModel().getObject().getDescription();
            }
            else return "";
        }
    });
    add(mll);


    Video video = new Video("myVideo", new Model<Exercise>(){
        @Override 
        public Exercise getObject() {  
            if (ExerciseDescriptionPanel.this.getModel().getObject() != null){
                return ExerciseDescriptionPanel.this.getModel().getObject();
            }
            else return new Exercise();
        }

    });
    add(video);
}
```

Well, what i dont understand is: While the Description is updated based on the current selection of the ListChoice, the Video-Class just ignores it and keeps returning the "new Exercise()", which schould only be returned at the first load of the ListChoice, when no selection is made.

I also provide you the Video-Class:

**Class Video**

```java
  public class Video extends Panel{

private IModel<Exercise> model;

public Video(String id, IModel<Exercise> model) {
    super(id, model);

    String src = ((Exercise)model.getObject()).getVideo();
    String startPicDest = ((Exercise)model.getObject()).getPicture();

WebMarkupContainer flashSrc = new WebMarkupContainer("flashSrcTag");
    flashSrc.add(new AttributeModifier("value", "config={'playlist':['" +
                startPicDest +"',{'url':'"+ src +"','autoPlay':false}]}")); 
    this.add(flashSrc); 

    setOutputMarkupId(true);
   }
}
```

Ive been searching through the internet for hours now, without finding anything helpful. 
Hope you guys are able to give me some solution to this problem. Thanks in regard. 
Greetings

Answer (score 2):

You're pulling the exercise out of the model once only:

```
public Video(String id, IModel<Exercise> model) {
  super(id, model);

  String src = ((Exercise)model.getObject()).getVideo();
  ...
}
```

How is this supposed to be up-to-date when the exercise changes later on?

You have to get the actual value for each render:

```
WebMarkupContainer flashSrc = new WebMarkupContainer("flashSrcTag") {
  public void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
    Exercise temp = (Exercise)model.getObject();
    String src = temp.getVideo();
    String startPicDest = temp.getPicture();

    tag.put("value", String.format("config={'playlist':['%s',{'url':'%s','autoPlay':false}]}", startPicDest, src)); 
  }
};
```

Comment: I totally missed that when reading the code. I think you're right, your answer is way more reasonable than mine.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. You are right, im still a wicket beginner and i really missed that.
THe Problem is, that its still not working. I put an info("test") in the onComponentTag-Method and also an feedbackpanel on the page, but it s never printed while switching through my listChoice. What else could i have done wrong?
Since the Model of the MultiLineLabel gets the update, the Model of the Video-Class must get it too. So the Model changes, but does that already mean, the onComponentTag is executed?

Comment: onComponentTag() is called for each rendering. When you refresh the ExerciseDescriptionPanel by adding it to the AjaxRequestTarget, all its children components will be re-rendererd too.

Add @Override to your onComponentTag() to make sure it has the right signature.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.
I added @Override to it, but it didnt work. The shown Video on my Page always says Clip: '[Clip] 'Null''. So i think its always Using the returned new Exercise() when loading the Page. Is there another way of getting the current model in the WebMarkupContainer of the Video-Class? The way of getting the Object in ExerciseDescriptionPanel "ExerciseDescriptionPanel.this.getModel().getObject()" isnt possible. I dont have any other ideas left...maybe changing the video-play, though i dun relly think that this would help.

Comment: **EDIT:** 
I just found out, that I forgot to delete the AttributeModifier...this caused the Problem. Stupid, but now its working. Thank you very much for your Time.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Please ignore this humble try to help you, svenmeier's answer is way better than mine.

I'm not 100% sure if this is true, but could it be related to the difference between your `Video` being a [MarkupContainer](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html) and the [MultiLineLabel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html) being a [WebComponent](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebComponent.html)?

Both the `Video` and the `MultiLineLabel` are added to the `ExerciseDescriptionPanel` in its constructor. If I understand the [Wicket documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/lifecycle-of-a-wicket-application.html#LifecycleofaWicketApplication-ModelChanges) correctly, as long as the surrounding `Page` and thus the `ExerciseDescriptionPanel` stay the same instance, the markup of the `Video` will not be regenerated. It says:

> A Page renders itself by rendering its associated markup (the html file that sits next to the Page). As MarkupContainer (the superclass for Page) iterates through the markup stream for the associated markup, it looks up components attached to the tags in the markup by id. Since the MarkupContainer (in this case a Page) is already constructed and initialized by onBeginRequest(), the child for each tag should be available in the container. Once the Component is retrieved, it's render() method is called.

Maybe you calling [modelChanged()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#modelChanged%28%29) on your `Video` once you change the Model of your `ExerciseDescriptionPanel` could indicate that the markup has to be refreshed.

Comment: Hey, thank you anyway. I also tried this out and it was worth a try :)